# Language split to minimize .apk file

Tags: android

I'm creating an app with 3 different languages. Every language contains a separate audio file (8 mb each).
Is it possible to split/export the project to 3 different .apk files prior to release on Market? I really do not want to put everything in one .apk due to the 24+ mb file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few options...

1. Manually build each one, release them as separate products in the Market in each language, e.g. "MyApp English", "MyApp Francais" etc. You could limit which countries see each one, to reduce confusion.
2. Same as above, but [use Ant to automate the Android build process](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html), so you can have one project for the app, but easily build a version in any language. Ant is quite involved, but I'd that in about a day you could learn enough to get an Ant build script running for your project. Android has built-in command line tools to help, so it'll create an initial Ant script for you (look at [the "android" command line tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)).
3. Create a single app, and when it starts, ask the user to confirm the language they want, and then start the download. Ideally you'd download a little bit initially to allow the app to work, and download the rest in the background so they don't have to wait. 8MB is quite a lot of data, so beware people will data expensive data plans so I think it is polite to always ask their permission for the download.

If it were me I'd probably lean towards the last option as it's simpler to build one app, and with sucha  big download, the user needs to be in control of the process. Bear in mind many people wouldn't download an 8MB app if they knew beforehand it is that big.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I havent decided which alternative to choose but probably the first or the second if I have the time to learn to setup ANT for android builds.

Comment: Restricting by country means that many expatriates/immigrants/travellers/minorities might not be able to download the app. Restricting by language would be the best, but unfortunately Play Store does not have this feature.

Comment: Today I would use Gradle in stead of Ant. It's relatively easy to configure!